# Pass data from controller action helper to view automatically in Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, helper, controller-action

I have created an actionHelper with a preDispatch function. I want this preDispatch to send some data to my view. Any idea how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alternatively (from within your action helper):

```
$view = $this->getActionController()->view;
$view->myKey = 'myValue';
```

An action helper is one of the few places in a ZF app that has direct access to the controller *instance* (as opposed to the controller *name*, which is accessible in lots of ways in various places).

Comment: It says undefined method getActionController()

Comment: @AbdulBasit Are you sure you are making this call from within your action-helper that extends `Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Abstract`? The method is there, certainly [since 1.12.0](https://github.com/zendframework/zf1/blob/release-1.12.0/library/Zend/Controller/Action/Helper/Abstract.php#L68)

Answer (score 1):

hey this would be as easy as this :)

```
$view = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getExistingHelper('ViewRenderer')->view; 
$view->your_param  = $your_value ;
```

then you could access it as usually

Answer (score 0):

```
$view = Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->getView();
$view->yourVar = 'test';
```